# SAML Logout in Websphere Liberty/Classic Websphere

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, websphere-8, websphere-liberty, adfs3.0

We are trying to achieve **SP-Initiated** SAML SSO with `ADFS`(our IDP) from WebSphere applications. We have used Liberty server which acts as the Service Provider/Relying Party. Using Liberty as a bridge we are able to do Sign-In for all applications deployed in classic WebSphere. But we are stuck at Logout process.

As of now WebSphere does not provide any SAML Logout feature. We tried using `session.invalidate()` method, also tried removing all cookies and `request.logout()` method. Though `request.logout()` removes the Authentication object, still we are able to access the application in the same browser session without any need to enter credentials.

We tried using `ADFS WS-Federation Sign-Out` URL mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx):

[https://{DNS_name_of_RP_STS}/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0](https://%7BDNS_name_of_RP_STS%7D/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0)

But as because Liberty is not able to handle Logout request and response, sign-out does not happen for WebSphere applications.

Are we following the correct approach? Is there any other work around for achieving Sign-Out?Is there a way to programmatically send SAML Logout request to ADFS from WebSphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we are able to achieve logout after the addition of logout functionality in Websphere Liberty by IBM as mentioned [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2018/03/16/single-logout-march-liberty-beta/). Liberty is working as SP/bridge for SAML login and logout and applications are deployed in Websphere Application Server.